optimized the SQL query to load results when total table contains 10 M records
SELECT 
    d.USPS_IMB AS IMb,
    d.CorrelationId,
    d.EINNo AS EIN,
    d.UniqueFormId AS FormId,
    d.ProductionFacility AS Facility,
    CASE 
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo < 5 THEN 'Received'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 5 THEN 'Printed'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 6 THEN 'Folded / Sealed'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 7 THEN 'Mailed'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS Status,
    d.StatusDateTime AS StatusDateUTC
FROM detail d
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        UniqueFormId,
        MAX(ProductionStatusNo) AS MaxProductionStatusNo
    FROM detail
    WHERE ProductionFacility='MAIL'
    GROUP BY UniqueFormId
) AS maxStatus
ON d.UniqueFormId = maxStatus.UniqueFormId AND d.ProductionStatusNo = maxStatus.MaxProductionStatusNo
WHERE d.ProductionFacility='MAIL';

I have above query on detail table and currently I have index on UniqueFormId, productionFacility as well on ProductionStatusNo .
I need suggestions to improve performance on this query so results can be loaded.
CREATE TABLE `detail` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 
  `EINNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Form` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionStatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionStatusNo` int NOT NULL,
  
  `StatusDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 
  `UniqueFormId` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionFacility` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  
  `USPS_IMB` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusDate` date DEFAULT NULL
 
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EINNo` (`EINNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EmployeeNo` (`EmployeeNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_Form` (`Form`),
  KEY `idx_detail_UniqueFormId` (`UniqueFormId`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionFacility` (`ProductionFacility`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionStatusNo` (`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_StatusDate` (`StatusDate`),
  
  KEY `idx_detail_PackageReference2` (`PackageReference2`),
  KEY `idx_detail_CartonID` (`CartonID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=216695199 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ProductionStatusNo`)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (13) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;


and currently I have index Provide this as complete CREATE TABLE.

Does (UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo) points to one row, or there may be some duplicates?

there could be duplicate . as some times data get repeated if there is no progress in terms of productionstatus.

You use partitioning by ProductionStatusNo and need to find MAX(ProductionStatusNo). So partition pruning cannot be applied. And I do not see the way for the query improve...

Okay understood is it possible to change this query so that it can return results in pages ? like 1st 100000 records and then after , so I am trying to less data into joins ?

When you limit the output then MySQL firstly obtains complete rowset and then returns needed rows amount. So the limitation will slow down the execution. From the other side you may obtain the matched rows from one or some partitions only (for detail AS d) which will be more fast.

what if I have temp table first with all ProductionFacility='MAIL' and then will work on that only , will that speed up the process ?

@rahularyansharma - "1st 100000" -- what will the client do with that much data !!  (And no, that is not likely to help any.)

@rahularyansharma - "temp table first" -- No.  It won't have any indexes.  Or, if you added indexes, that would be the slow part of the task.

In the derived table (which will probably be run first), detail needs
INDEX(ProductionFacility, UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo)

with the columns in the indicated order.
The outer SELECT will also like that index.
The given PARTITIONing probably slows down the query.  Please explain why you chose it.
Given that composite index, this is no longer useful (so DROP it):
KEY `idx_detail_ProductionFacility` (`ProductionFacility`)

Note:  Three Single-column indexes will not do as good as the "composite" index I suggest.
The size of ProductionFacility varchar(450) NOT NULL -- may give you trouble.  Shrink the size and/or normalize it.  Ditto for UniqueFormId.
For further discussion, please provide EXPLAIN SELECT.
(Alas, if you really have 216695199 rows, the ALTERs I am suggesting will take a long time.)

To optimize your SQL query you can try the following:
Create a composite index:
CREATE INDEX idx_detail_facility_form_status ON detail (ProductionFacility, UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo);

Reevaluate partitioning by possibly using ProductionFacility:
ALTER TABLE detail
PARTITION BY RANGE (ProductionFacility) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('A'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('B'),
    -- add additional partitions as needed
);

Optimize the subquery:
SELECT 
    UniqueFormId,
    MAX(ProductionStatusNo) AS MaxProductionStatusNo
FROM detail
WHERE ProductionFacility = 'MAIL'
GROUP BY UniqueFormId;

Create an additional index:
CREATE INDEX idx_detail_formid_status ON detail (UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo);

Analyze the query execution plan:
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    d.USPS_IMB AS IMb,
    d.CorrelationId,
    d.EINNo AS EIN,
    d.UniqueFormId AS FormId,
    d.ProductionFacility AS Facility,
    CASE 
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo < 5 THEN 'Received'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 5 THEN 'Printed'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 6 THEN 'Folded / Sealed'
        WHEN d.ProductionStatusNo = 7 THEN 'Mailed'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS Status,
    d.StatusDateTime AS StatusDateUTC
FROM detail d
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        UniqueFormId,
        MAX(ProductionStatusNo) AS MaxProductionStatusNo
    FROM detail
    WHERE ProductionFacility='MAIL'
    GROUP BY UniqueFormId
) AS maxStatus
ON d.UniqueFormId = maxStatus.UniqueFormId AND d.ProductionStatusNo = maxStatus.MaxProductionStatusNo
WHERE d.ProductionFacility='MAIL';

Ensure data types and schema are optimized and perform regular maintenance tasks such as ANALYZE TABLE to keep statistics up-to-date.
